# How to get the starting cell and ending cell address of a specific matching value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find the starting cell number and the ending cell number of a specific value. For example if I have this excel sheet:

[image: example excel sheet]

Here, I when I search for “10:” in the formula, I should get:

**A1:A5**

For example there’s this formula `=COUNTIF(range, text)` using this formula I can count the number of times that certain text is being repeated. Now I need a formula where when I enter a text, it should tell me the starting cell number and the ending cell number.

I hope I’m clear. Is this possible?

Comment: Why was it important to center-align all values? If you hadn't we could at least tell whether your times are text or true times.

Comment: @Jeeped I’m sorry I used excel on my phone that’s why. And they are not times, they are basic text or just simple numbers.

Comment: @pnuts what exactly isn’t clear? I’ll try to explain clearly.

Comment: Uh, yeah ... sure. Let me know when you get off your phone.

Comment: @pnuts For example there’s this formula ‘=COUNTIF(range, text)’ using this formula I can count the number of times that certain text is being repeated. Now I need a formula where when I enter a text, it should tell me the starting cell number and the ending cell number.

Comment: And we get to assume column A is sorted and your value is always at the beginning (so in particular, we could match VAL*)?

Comment: @pnuts done editing main post. And what I mean by that is, the text that I wanna search would be in the first column.

Comment: @JeremyKahan what I mean is the text that I want to search the first and last cell is in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You need `=iferror("A"&MATCH("10*",A:A,0) & ":A"&MATCH("10*",A:A),"")` if you were searching for things that begin with 10. You can change 10 to a cell reference so long as you & "*" onto that.
The first MATCH piece gives the first matching row number in the range (which since I am looking at the whole column is the row number) and the second gives the last that is <= (in our case = because we found a first that is =). If we find nothing, the iferror handles that and returns blank for the whole thing.
The above is assuming column A is formatted as text (and sorted -- it is not meant to handle if the matching entries were in a1:a3 and then there was another in A7).